# Longest consecutive path in a matrix of letters

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, data-structures

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Given a matrix of n * m, with letters(characters), find the longest consecutive path of letters in the matrix and output the string. For example:

```
m = [[a,c,d],[i,b,e],[h,g,f]]

result = e,f,g,h
```

You can only move up, down, left, right inside the matrix. This is what I have come up so far following some information online, but I'm not all the way there. 
I would also like to make the solution efficient, my current code might have too many loops and is probably slow for a large matrix. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
R = len(matrix)
C = len(matrix[0])

x = [0, 1, 0, -1]
y = [1, 0, -1, 0]

dp=[[0 for i in range(C)]for i in range(R)]

def isvalid( i, j):
    if (i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= R or j >= C):
        return False
    return True

def getLenUtil(matrix, i, j, prev):
    if (isvalid(i, j)==False or isadjacent(prev, mat[i][j])==False):
        return 0
    if (dp[i][j] != -1):
        return dp[i][j]

    ans = 0

    for k in range(4):
        ans = max(ans, 1 + getLenUtil(mat, i + x[k],j + y[k], mat[i][j]))

    dp[i][j] = ans
    return dp[i][j]

def isadjacent(prev, curr):
    if (ord(curr) -ord(prev)) == 1:
        return True
    return False

def findLongestSequence(matrix):
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            dp[i][j]=-1
    ans = 0
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            if (mat[i][j] == s):
                for k in range(4):
                    ans = max(ans, 1 + getLenUtil(matrix, i + x[k], j + y[k], s));
     return ans
```

Comment: Where did you define `s`? There also seems a mismatch between `mat` and `matrix`. Did you debug this code?

Comment: Why is the answer for the example 4, when there is a path from "b" to "i"? Why is it not 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues in your code:

- `mat` and `matrix` spelling should be unified.
- `s` is never initialised
- In `R = len(matrix)` and several other references to `mat` or `matrix`, that variable is not defined. `findLongestSequence` is called with the actual value of `matrix`, so it is there there `R` should be defined, ...etc

Also,

- it is easier if you don't pass `prev`, but the actual *expected* character (that is already "incremented").
- Why first initialise `dp` with zeroes, when then you re-initialise with -1? Just use -1 immediately.

Here is how it could work:

```
def findLongestSequence(mat):
    R = len(mat)
    C = len(mat[0])

    x = [0, 1, 0, -1]
    y = [1, 0, -1, 0]

    dp = [[-1 for i in range(C)] for i in range(R)]

    def isvalid( i, j):
        return (0 <= i < R) and (0 <= j < C)

    def getLenUtil(mat, i, j, expected):
        if not isvalid(i, j) or mat[i][j] != expected:
            return 0

        if dp[i][j] == -1:
            ans = 0
            expected = chr(ord(mat[i][j])+1)
            for k in range(4):
                ans = max(ans, 1 + getLenUtil(mat, i + x[k], j + y[k], expected))

            dp[i][j] = ans
        return dp[i][j]

    ans = 0
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            getLenUtil(mat, i, j, mat[i][j])
        ans = max(ans, max(dp[i]))
    print(dp)
    return ans

res = findLongestSequence([["a","c","d"],["i","b","e"],["h","g","f"]])
print(res)
```

Note that for this example data the returned answer is 8, not 4, as the longest sequence starts with "b" and ends with "i" -- 8 characters in total.

Comment: Thanks so much, yeah I made some mistakes with the syntax and it wasn't consistent. This is a way easier way of doing it. What would you suggest I do if instead of showing the length of the consecutive characters, I want to output the characters themselves?

Comment: You would return a list. So `return 0` becomes `return []`, `ans = 0` becomes `ans = []`. `ans = max(....)` becomes something more complex where you would compare `len(ans)` with the length of the recursive return. If the latter is equal or longer, then let `ans` be that returned list plus the current letter, otherwise don't touch it.

Comment: Have a go at it. If you bump into an issue then ask a new question about it.